# How to print console output in pyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, adb

I need to display adb logs in a Pyqt window, i tried like this. When i click the button log_display function is called, which set the console output to textBrowser. I tried to use subprocess but it didn't help, the window is just freezing and not responding. What is the way to do it? Maybe i need to use new thread for it?

```
def log_display(self):
    result = subprocess.run('adb logcat *:I', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    self.textBrowser.setText(subprocess.run('result.stdout'))
```

Comment: No you don't need a thread necessarily. But this part does not make sense, self.textBrowser.setText(subprocess.run('result.stdout'))

Answer (score 0):

You have to use QProcess since it launches the application but does not block the GUI since it notifies the log through signals:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class LogView(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess()
        self._process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
        self._process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)

    def start_log(self, program, arguments=None):
        if arguments is None:
            arguments = []
        self._process.start(program, arguments)

    def add_log(self, message):
        self.appendPlainText(message.rstrip())

    def handle_stdout(self):
        message = self._process.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        self.add_log(message)

    def handle_stderr(self):
        message = self._process.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.add_log(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = LogView()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    w.start_log("adb", ["logcat", "*:I"])

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```